# How to avoid OutOfMemoryError even after having used the Loading Large Bitmap Efficiently guidelines

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, android-imageview, setimagebitmap

I'm trying to setImageBitmap but I keep getting the following OutOfMemoryError even after I have implemented the guidelines here https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 11345668 byte allocation with 1206384 free bytes and 1178KB until OOM
        at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:620)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:455)
        at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:478)
        at com.example.myapp.ImageOptimized.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(ImagenOptimizada.java:50)
        at com.example.myapp.Game3Players.onAnimationEnd(Game3Players.java:511)
        at android.view.animation.Animation$3.run(Animation.java:381)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

This is the part of the code where I use the method. I randomly choose one card to show one image, and the rest will show another:

```
ImageView[] cardsArray = new ImageView[3];
            cardsArray[0]=cardOne;
            cardsArray[1]=cardTwo;
            cardsArray[2]=cardThree;

            final int index = new Random().nextInt(cardsArray.length);                                
            cardsArray[index].setImageBitmap(ImageOptimized.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.skull, 250, 250));     

            for (int i=0; i<cardsArray.length; i++){                                                  

                if (cardsArray[index]!=cardsArray[i]){
                    cardsArray[i].setImageBitmap(ImageOptimized.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.safe, 250, 250));
                }

            }
```

I first tried this because, since I'm replacing an image for another, I want to use the same width and height:

```
cardsArray[index].setImageBitmap(ImageOptimized.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), R.drawable.skull, cardsArray[index].getWidth(), cardsArray[index].getHeight()));
```

But this was giving me an error right away. That's why I decided to use a fixed size, 250, but it keeps throwing me the error. What's funny is that sometimes the code runs without a problem, but then when the operation is repeated - maybe the third, fourth, sometimes fifth time - it crashes. Am I possibly doing something wrong which leads to a memory leak maybe?

Just in case you also wanna take a look to the class where I follow the guidelines:

```
public class ImageOptimized {


    public static int calculateInSampleSize(
            BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) >= reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) >= reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }


    public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
                                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
    }

}
```

Comment: Where do you have the image? I mean in which folder?

Comment: drawable folder @Skizo-ozᴉʞS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use loading and caching image libraries for better performance such as [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) or [Picasso](https://square.github.io/picasso/).

Usage of Glide, for example, is pretty simple:

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.safe).into(imageView);
```

You can resize them too:

```
Glide.with(this).load(R.drawable.safe).apply(new RequestOptions().override(250, 250).into(imageView);
```

Most of these libraries handle by their own the cleaning of resources they used; which means that they handle memory efficiently.

Also try not to use very large resolution images and use PNG format if you can choose.

Comment: this ended up being a good way to solve the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem days ago, I missed the copy/paste of my drawable and instead of putting it on `drawable-hdpi` (for instance) I put it on `drawable` folder, without extension, moving the drawable to a drawable folder with extension worked for me.

Also you can add these lines into your `manifest.xml`

> android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
>
> android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: But that means my images will only be visible on devices with that resolution, if someone views the content from a device that is not hdpi then it will crash right?

Comment: No it won't, otherwise what you can do is : [NativeScript Image Builder](http://nsimage.brosteins.com/) to get the images with all of the extensions.